# What are the different delivery statuses and what do they mean?

Tags: google-messages

I've seen a number of different status after sending a message, but what are they and what do they mean. Many of these are pretty clear to me what they mean and some not so clear.

What I've seen and what I assume it means:

- Sent - It is sent from my carrier
- Delivered - It is received from the recipient's carrier
- Received - It is received on the recipient's phone
- Read - It is read from the recipient
- Seen - It is seen from the recipient

There's probably more. But what's unclear to me is what's the difference between "Read" and "Seen." Is there a corresponding "outbox" status if my phone is unable to send as there are "delivered/received" statuses for the recipient side?

Comment: Seen could mean that the notification message was shown to the user. Read could mean the full message was shown e.g. in the app.

Comment: That was my initial thought. I often view most messages through notifications and don't bother to open the app itself. Also wonder if it is any different for devices that can pick up notifications to display elsewhere (such as a smart watch) and if the act of retrieving it is considered "seen" even if you never actually look at it.